# Присваивание переменных в Python

Tags: python

Есть словарь:

```
l={'a':1,'b':2}
```

Потом я получаю значение переменных

```
>>>globals().update(l)
>>>print a
1
>>>print b
2
```

Есть переменная 'c'. как сделать так чтобы значение 'a' и 'b' присваивались 'с' поочередно, я так понял нужен цикл, но пока не пойму как его составить. Может кто сталкивался, подскажите.

/// пример кода:

```
import subprocess

l={'a':'google.com', 'b':'ya.ru', 'd':'blogspot.com'}
globals().update(l)

for i in ('a','b','d'):
    host = globals()[i]

    ping = subprocess.Popen(
        ["ping", "-n", "4", host],
        stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr = subprocess.PIPE
    )
out, error = ping.communicate()
if ping.communicate() !=1:
    print 'ok'
else:
    print 'false'
```

Разобрался вот правильный блок проверки в цикле for:

```
    out,error = ping.communicate()
    if ping.returncode != 0 :
         print 'false'
    else:
        print 'ok'
```

Comment: а если нужно чтобы 'c' сначала приняла значение 'a' цикл прошел, а потом 'c' приняла значение 'b', и так пока переменные не закончатся, это нужно цикл while сделать?

Comment: Что значит "цикл прошёл"? Выполнилась какая-то обработка? Так выполняйте её в теле цикла `for`. Тело может быть большим.

Comment: Цикл пошел, то есть, переменная "с" приняла сначала значение "а", программа сделала какие-то махинации с "с", потом программа вернулась и "с" приняла значение "b", опять программа делает какие-то махинации c "с", итак пока не закончатся переменные,в общем перебор.

Comment: Замените строку `print c` на ваше:

> программа сделала какие-то махинации с "с"

и получится тот алгоритм, который вы описали.

Comment: У меня "с" присваивает значения и "a", и "b" , но операция производится только над значением "b". А хотелось бы чтобы было с = a => операция, потом c = b => операция.

Comment: Скорее всего, вы действие выполняете вне тела цикла. Текст -- в студию. Правда это питон, отступы...

Comment: в правке пример кода.

Comment: Popen -- в теле цикла. А вот communicate (если форматирование не нарушено) -- вне. Т.е. communicate только для последнего значения ping

Comment: я еще поправил код communicate в теле, но все значения в ок, хотя должны 1 и 3 в false.

Comment: > `if ping.communicate() !=1:`

Это не правильно. Ошибочным кодом ответа является любое число отличное от нуля, а не только `1`. Т.е. успешный пинг может быть только если команда вернула `0`.

Comment: поправил) Спасибо за поправку.

Comment: @IlyaPirogov: `.communicate()` возвращает tuple (stdout, stderr) содержимое -- не имеет отношения к .returncode. В любом случае повторный вызов `.communicate()` ошибочен здесь (если .communicate() без исключения завершился, то процесс мёртв, ввод/вывод завершился).

Comment: вместо манипуляций имён a,b,c, используя globals() (не нужно так делать), можно использовать коллекцию urls в вашем цикле (`urls = 'google.com', 'ya.ru', 'blogspot.com'` и позже `for url in urls: ...`)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
for c in l.values():
    print(c)
```

**UPD**.

```
import os
import subprocess

l = {'a':'google.com', 'b':'ya.ru', 'd':'blogspot.com'}

for key, host in l.items():

    with open(os.devnull, 'w') as devnull:
        return_code = subprocess.call(['ping', '-n', '4', host], stdout=devnull, stderr=devnull)

    if not return_code:
        print('%s, %s: ok' % (key, host))
    else:
        print('%s, %s: failed' % (key, host))
```

И не понятно зачем вам тут `globals()`

Comment: Обновил ответ.

Answer (score 2):

```
for i in ('a', 'b'):
    c = globals()[i]
    print c
```